# How can I compile and sign Grub in a way that Secure Boot will allow?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

Since the file .efi of Grub2 compiled by myself hasn’t gone through code signing (such as EV code signing certificate), and now my program (.efi file) can’t boot computers which have enabled Secure Boot!

My question is that can EV Code Signing Certificate solve this problem? Are there any other solutions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a new rsa key and certificate pair with `openssl`:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:<BITS> 
            -keyout <PRIVATE_KEY_PATH> 
            -outform PEM 
            -out <CRT_CERTIFICATE_PATH>
```

Then use `sbsign` (or the sign-file inside `linux-headers` in `/usr/src`):

```
sbsign --key <PRIVATE_KEY> --cert <CRT_CERTIFICATE>
       --output <SIGNED_GRUB_PATH>
       <UNSIGNED_GRUB_PATH>
```

Generate the DER certificate and import it into the firmware:

```
openssl x509 -in <CRT_CERTIFICATE_PATH>
             -outform DER
             -out <DER_CERTIFICATE_PATH>

sudo mokutil --import <DER_CERTIFICATE_PATH>
```